# Storage permissions for downloading a pdf for Android 10 and above

Tags: android

I am working on an existing app and I need to change the storage permissions for Android 13 especially. I've read that for Android 10 and above WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not mandatory, so I used the following:

```
private fun checkStoragePermissions(): Boolean {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
    return true
   }

   val permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
   return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Will the download work fine just by not requesting the permission or do I need to do something extra?

Comment: You do not need any permission but INTERNET to download files from internet.

Comment: That depends on *specifically* where you are looking to write the data (and, somewhat, on how you plan on doing the download). I recommend that you update your question with those sorts of details.